# Change image src inside jquery slider using radio buttons

Tags: html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

Ok so basically im trying to build a "vehicle colour configurator" inside a jquery image slider. I want people to be able to click on a styled radio button and have that particular slides img src amended accordingly. This is my code below but i cannot get the images to change...

HTML

```
<div data-iview:image="features/design/design_5.1.jpg" id="config">
            <div class="iview-caption design5" data-transition="fade">
                <h1>Colour</h1><h2>the town...</h2>
                <p>Blah blah fish paste</p>
                <span>
                 <input type="radio" name="config" value='design_5.1.jpg' />
                 <input type="radio" name="config" value='design_5.2.jpg' />
                 <input type="radio" name="config" value='design_5.3.jpg' />
                 <input type="radio" name="config" value='design_5.4.jpg' />
                 <input type="radio" name="config" value='design_5.5.jpg' />
                 <input type="radio" name="config" value='design_5.6.jpg' />
                 <input type="radio" name="config" value='design_5.7.jpg' />
                 <input type="radio" name="config" value='design_5.8.jpg' />
                </span>
            </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
imgFldr = 'features/design/'; 

$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {   
  $('#config').attr('data-iview', imgFldr+this.value);
});
```

Comment: what the hell is `data-iview:image`?

Answer (score 0):

That `data-iview:image` is translated to css background property at runtime, therefore changing it dinamically doesn't affect anything on the slider

Comment: Thanks for all the responses thus far guys! So David you are saying that they way Iview calls its slides is basically background images?

Answer (score 0):

You miss ':image',and the code is like this

```
$(function(){
var imgFldr = 'features/design/'; 
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {   
$('#config').attr('data-iview:image', imgFldr+this.value);
});})
```

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately it is still not working :-(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a different solution based on the following:

```html
//The color picker div    
<div class="picker" data-bkgnd="/content/images/someimg.jpg"></div>

//The container for your product image
<div class="productDisplay"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".picker").click(function(){       
       //Load background string from data of clicked element
       var bVal = $(this).attr('data-bkgnd');
       //Set display's background to retrieved background string
       $(".productDisplay").hide().css({'background-image': "url(" + bVal + ")"}).show();
   });
 });

</script>
```